# Find sign change in set of positive and negative numbers using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have set of numbers, in which column index 3 has negative and positive numbers, so there is change of pattern from positive to negative. How to check this using Numpy array, I am thinking to count the sum of column and if its less then number of rows then there is a sign change happend. Is there any function in Numpy to do it more efficiently, may be something like `XOR` ?

```
import numpy as np
t = [[363.57, 363.57, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [385.41, 385.41, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [406.12, 406.12, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [424.2, 424.2, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [444.91, 444.91, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [468.26, 468.26, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1]]

x = np.array(t)
x[:, 3]
```

I dont like below solution, because its too bulky if I have more than 100 K Rows.

```
if sum(x[:, 3]) <= x.shape[0]:
   print("sign change happend")
```

I can change the datastructure, that is how I am storing it in variable `t`. trying to do it in more efficient and fast way using numpy.

#### expected output

```
if col_3_sign_changed: 
   # do something
```

Comment: What is your desired output? just a boolean that wether column 3 has more than one sign?

Comment: yes, just boolean

Comment: I think your already suggested solution is pretty good. Maybe you want to use sign to account for non-unit values as well `np.sign(x[:,3]).sum()<x.shape[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

```
np.any(np.diff(x[:,3]))
```

or (suggested in question):

```
np.sign(x[:,3]).sum()<x.shape[0]
```

or (as suggested by @Prune):

```
np.any(np.roll(x[:,3],1)!=x[:,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be clearer, but if you are looking for whether there are positive and negative values vs just positive, something this simple will suffice:

```
value_signs = set(np.sign(x[:,3]).flatten())

if len(value_signs) == 2:
    print("positive and negative signs present")
else:
    print("just one sign present")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specification allows a variety of values, not merely +1 and -1.  I recommend that you use the following steps:

- create a vector of Booleans, indicating + and - values
- `shift` the vector one position
- compare the shifted vector with the original

You can do this in one line, if you like.

Can you handle the coding from there?

Comment: what is shift vector means?

Comment: What did you not understand when you looked up "numpy shift"?

Comment: Do you mean `np.any(np.roll(x[:,3],1)!=x[:,3])`? If so, this is another way but I think would be slower.

Comment: got it, trying to understand `shift`